# Can I set the debugVisualizerCamera roll orientation in pybullet?

Tags: python, pybullet

I would like to set the camera's yaw, pitch, and roll to follow a drone I have flying around a simulation.

I'm aware of `p.resetDebugVisualizerCamera(cameraDistance=3, cameraYaw=30, cameraPitch=52, cameraTargetPosition=[0,0,0])`. Using this, I have it following my drone's position, yaw, and pitch, but that doesn't give me the ability to set roll. I've tried looking for another way to fully control the orientation of the camera but I haven't found any others. Maybe there's a piece of documentation I've missed?

Thank you